# Difficulty with LevelSpec. Product of empty set should be 1

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a matrix

```
newm = {{{}, {}, {-p}}, {{d}, {e}, {p}}, {{g}, {h}, {i}}};
MatrixForm[newm};
```

whose elements are lists.

I would like to multiply the elements of a part of a row, for instance the last two elements of row 1, in such a way that the empty set contributes 1 to the product. This code does the job:

```
Apply[Times, {newm[[1, 2 ;; -1]]}, 2][[1]]
```

But it seems overly complicated, i.e. having to wrap the part `newm[[1, 2 ;; -1]]` in curly braces, and specify level 2 for the `Times` command, and then extract the first (only) element of the answer.

Is there a more elegant way ?

I have been experimenting with Levelspec but this is the only thing I can find that works.

Comment: Why are you wrapping the individual elements in `{}`? Why don't you replace `{-p}` with `-p`, for instance, and replace the `{}`s with `1`s?

Comment: Thank you for responding, march. My matrix is an adjacency matrix for a graph with weighted, labelled edges. Hence each element is a list of real numbers, such as `{p,p^2}`. It is true that for this particular application, the lists are all either singleton sets such as `{p}`, or `{1-p^2}`, or the empty set `{}`. Therefore in this case I could pre-process the matrix by removing the curly braces from all the singletons, and replacing all the empty sets by 1.

Comment: `n = newm /. {} -> {1}; h @@ n[[1, 2 ;; -1, 1]]` Use `h` as you please, for example `h = Times`

Comment: That's what I would do. In that case, you would do `Times @@ newm[[1, 2 ;; -1]]`. Perhaps you could post the more general case?

Comment: Thank you both very much ! I am convinced that your approach is the best: Convert {} to 1 first. I realise I don't understand the part specification well. I should use `[[1,2;;-1,1]]` as belisarius is forth does, instead of `[[1,2;;-1]]`, which I have been using. The 1,2 means start from the element in the 1st row and 2nd column. The -1 means continue until the last element (but why should that mean the last element of this particular *row* ?) And the final 1 seems to mean to take the first column ? But why ? I find the documentation a bit vague on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more general case, as mentioned in comments:

```
newm = {{{}, {}, {2, 2}, {-p, p^2}}, {{d}, {}, {e}, {p}}, {{g}, {}, {h}, {i}}};
MatrixForm[newm]
```

> [image]

One way is to raplace `{}` with `{1}` and we can take specific part from `newm` to apply `Times` to.

Or

```
Composition[
  Apply[Times],
  First,
  Flatten[#, {{2}, {1}}] &,  (*transposition of ragged array*)
  #[[1, 2 ;;]] &             (*row and row's part spec*)
  ] @ newm
```

> ```
> -2 p
> ```